zen 4 ok but zen 5 causes usb/audio issues?
ok I have two computers.. AM5 DDR5, one has a 8600g and one has a 9700x
my setup uses USB Audio speakers (Kali Audio LP-UNF) attached via USB.
Both have windows 11 with all windows updates.
with the PC with AMD 8600G, everything is great!
with a nearly identical PC except it has a 9700X , the sound will be fine and then within a minute or two it goes all white noise like an old TV without an active input.
If i unplug the usb speakers, and plug em back in, it's back to normal... only to go all white noise within a minute or so.  the noise is super loud and horrible.
What's crazy is in my 2 PCs i swapped processors on a whim, and the problem followed the 9700X, and the previously misbehaving system is now fine with the 8600g!  whatever pc the 9700X is in , these usb audio speakers behave this way.
I'm not really sure what to make of it.    Thoughts?

Did you update drivers and firmware?

yup, everything is latest
